# What is equivalent type of vector<Point> and Mat in EMGU?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Here is OpenCV types:

```
vector<Point> vectorPoint;
Mat mat;
```

What is equivalent types in EMGU of the types above?

Comment: As of EmguCV v3.1 , above answer still applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat mat; changes to

```
Matrix<TDepth> mat;
```

which is in the Emgu.CV namespace. TDepth would be float, int, etc.

vector vectorPoint; changes to

```
VectorOfPoint vectorPoint;
```

which is in Emgu.CV.Util

I am not sure the earliest version of EMGU that VectorOfPoint is in, but it is not in as of 2.2.1.  The latest as of this posting is 2.4.2, so it's likely in by now.